# WINDOWS 8.1 Pro User folder questions and accounts

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

Have a some questions.  Backgroup  -I built two PCs and i didn't have network drivers enabled.  So both installs created a local admin account during installation.  One later asked me if I wanted a Microsoft Account to replace this, I said yes while I entered that account.  The other didn't for some reason.  The PCs are used for music/picture/video storage sharing in household (and a backup storage space for other pcs on one of them).  I have two Microsoft User account on them ; one acts like a Private Guest account (family knows password), The other is my account.   Here are questions.

1)First computer -  Have a user folder for an account/user that doesn't exist, the user is already deleted.  How do I delete it?  I think I saw someone state to do it in safe mode, will try but will it leave a bunch of crap in the registry?

2)Second computer - Don't mind the name of user folders being xxxxx_000.  But the one that Microsoft switched from a local to Microsoft account, kept the same name as the local account for the folder!!  So I have an account xxxxx, and a user folder of yyyyy, I can handle the xxxxx-000 naming, but the yyyyy (a little pun).   I assume I can sign into my account, delete the common house account.  Maybe reboot into safe mode, and delete the folder for that account I just deleted.  Then reboot normal, and add the account back, sign out and then into this account. .. But here is the question, I have spotify and dbPoweramp installed, a few other programs on desktop as well. When I delete the account are these apps still available (I would assume they are installed still), and if so, when I add back the account how do I get the "desktop apps" back.  Really concerned about dbPoweramp, because it adds some commands in file explorer when you right click on music or videos...

Last - with the house account on two pcs, how do I get them to sync there settings (roaming profiles).  I don't know if they are link to roam, it would be great if I installed an application on one of the PCs, and it showed up on the other, can this be done (with desktop apps)? I know somethings can roam like background pics.. If so, I would like to have them synced before I delete the account on the PC, so when I add it back all the stuff will show up and save me a lot of time.

Anyway this is long and would appreciate any answers/ inout.